# ComboBox.Focus() not working on form load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void InvoiceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     comboBox2.Focus();
     lstinv = invhnd.Get();// lstinv is inventry type list 
     comboBox2.DataSource = lstinv;
     comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
     comboBox2.ValueMember = "ItemPrice";           
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ ? Any exception or error message? What does `Get()` method do? A little bit explanation would be helpful..

Comment: i just want that whenever the form open combobox should be on focus

Comment: use ComboBox.Select Method

Comment: get() method just collect the no of records from database and put it in the list(lstinv)

Comment: Have you tried the forms `Shown` event? That fires when the form is shown, whereas you should be able to focus the combobox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use ComboBox.Select Method

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **tabindex** property of combobox to Zero, but remember you will need to change the tabindex property of other controls having the value 0)