# How can i working calculator to only in keyboard to use keys.add

Tags: c#

I Want to make a calculator to working only with the keyboard.
And I want to react combo box if I press (+,-,*,/) on textbox1 
but the problem is when I press (+,-,*,/) on the keyboard, it doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "+")
        {
            int tmp = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            textBox3.Text = tmp.ToString();
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "-")
        {
            int tmp = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) - int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            textBox3.Text = tmp.ToString();
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "*")
        {
            int tmp = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) * int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            textBox3.Text = tmp.ToString();
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "/")
        {
            int tmp = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) / int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            textBox3.Text = tmp.ToString();
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e .KeyCode == Keys.Add )
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "+";
            textBox2.Focus();
            textBox2.SelectAll();
        }
        if (e .KeyCode == Keys.Subtract )
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "-";
            textBox2.Focus();
            textBox2.SelectAll();
        }

        if (e .KeyCode == Keys.Multiply )
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "*";
            textBox2.Focus();
            textBox2.SelectAll();
        }

        if (e .KeyCode == Keys.Divide )
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "/";
            textBox2.Focus();
            textBox2.SelectAll();
        }



    }

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e .KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
        {
            this.button1_Click(sender, e);
            textBox1.Focus();
            textBox1.SelectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make work only in keyboard and when I press (+,-,*,/) on textbox1, focus need to go textbox2 with changing comboBox.

[in order, textBox1, comboBox1, textBox2, button, textBox3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WVpy.jpg)

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031080/calculator-keypress

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: See this regarding getting change of focus to work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594194/textbox-focus-not-working-in-c-sharp & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910333/combobox-focus-not-working-on-form-load

Comment: See example here for handling both KeyDown and KeyPress events to stop characters being entered into TextBox : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks all. I found another problem. Keys.Add-> Keys.Oemplus / Keys.Subtract -> Keys.OemMinus it work. I don't know why..

Comment: @XSpace it is working because Keys.Add only works if you are tiping + from the keyboard numpad. See my answer. If you modify it like I did then no matter from where the input comes from the keyboard because you are checking for char '+'

Comment: @SlavenHvar I see. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only works if you are tiping `+,-,*,/` from the numpad of your keyboard.
Change your `textBox1_KeyDown` to `textBox1_KeyPress` event. That gives you the ability to check the input char from your keyboard (`+,-,*,/`):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '+')
    {
        comboBox1.Text = "+";
        textBox2.Focus();
        textBox2.SelectAll();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '-')
    {
        comboBox1.Text = "-";
        textBox2.Focus();
        textBox2.SelectAll();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '*')
    {
        comboBox1.Text = "*";
        textBox2.Focus();
        textBox2.SelectAll();
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '/')
    {
        comboBox1.Text = "/";
        textBox2.Focus();
        textBox2.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: It work! Thanks a lot. I wander why (+,-,*,/) this code work only numpad on my keyboard

Comment: Because Keys.Add checks for the + sign on the numpad of the keyboard and Keys.Oemplus checks for the other + sign on your keyboard. But if you check for the input char like I did it doesn't matter from where the input came.